# Best method to get variable that does not equal a count function parameter?

Tags: python, count

I am using the count function to check if exactly 2 out of 3 variables are equal to a number. After the function is called, is there an easier or better way to find the variable that did not equal the number in the count function than what I did below? I am looking for a pure Python solution without packages.

This is what I am currently using to get the variable that does not equal the count function parameter:

```
num1 = 5
num2 = 7
num3 = 5
list = [num1, num2, num3]

if list.count(5) == 2:
    for e in list:
        if e != 5:
            print(e)
```

I am using Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this counts as "easier", but it's certainly shorter to do this:

```
list = [5,7,5]
[x for x in list if x != 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `numpy`'s vectorized operations, which are fast and very intuitive.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,7,10])
```

Then

```
>>> a == 5
array([ True, False, False])

>>> (a == 5).sum() # how many are equal to 5?
1

>>> a[a!=5]
array([ 7, 10])
```

Of course, please let know if you need a pure python approach.

Comment: Oh, I am looking for a pure python solution. Thanks

Comment: @Kyle Then there's not much you can do, I'd say. Maybe make your for loop a one-line list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You want to print the variable whose count is not 2

```
lst = [5, 7 , 5]

for i in lst:
    if lst.count(i) != 2:
        print(i)

# 7
```

Or

```
print(*(i for i in lst if lst.count(i) != 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def single(tri):
    return tri[2] if tri[0] == tri[1] else tri[:2][tri[0] == tri[2]]
```

It uses the coercion `False = 0` and `True = 1`. 
In contrast to the list expressions, it tests only exactly 2 times for equality (the list expressions test 3 times). So this might be the fastest solution available. Test:

```
single([5, 5, 7]) ## 7
single([5, 7, 5]) ## 7
single([7, 5, 5]) ## 7
```